# javascript .children not working in Camino Browser

Tags: javascript, camino

This is an odd one, for whatever reason, getting the children of an element doens't work in Camino browser. Works in all other browsers. Anyone know how to fix this? Google is no help :(

```
var site_result_content = document.getElementById(content_id);
    site_child_nodes = site_result_content.children;
    alert('started');
    for(i=0;i<site_child_nodes.length;i++) {
        alert('cycle1');
        document.getElementById(site_child_nodes[i].id).className = 'tab_content';
        ShowHide(site_child_nodes[i].id,'hidden');
    }
```

In this case, the started alert is called, but the cycle1 isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `childNodes` instead. `children` started out as a proprietary property that in IE, whereas `childNodes` is in the W3C DOM spec and is supported by every major browser released in the last decade. The difference is that `children` contains only elements whereas `childNodes` contains of all types, in particular text nodes and comment nodes.

I've optimized your code below. You should declare all your variables with `var`, including those used in loops such as `i`. Also, `document.getElementById(site_child_nodes[i].id)` is unnecessary: it will fail if the element has no ID and is exactly the same as `site_child_nodes[i]` otherwise.

```
var site_result_content = document.getElementById(content_id);
var site_child_nodes = site_result_content.childNodes;
alert('started');
for (var i = 0, len = site_child_nodes.length; i < len; ++i) {
    if (site_child_nodes[i].nodeType == 1) {
        alert('cycle1');
        site_child_nodes[i].className = 'tab_content';
        ShowHide(site_child_nodes[i].id, 'hidden');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd hazard a guess that it's not been implemented yet (it was only implemented in Firefox 3.5).  You can use `childNodes` instead, which returns a list of nodes (rather than just elements).  Then check `nodeType` to make sure it's an element.

```
var site_result_content = document.getElementById(content_id);
site_child_nodes = site_result_content.childNodes;
alert('started');
for(i=0;i<site_child_nodes.length;i++) {
    // Check this is actually an element node
    if (site_child_nodes[i].nodeType != 1)
        continue;

    alert('cycle1');
    document.getElementById(site_child_nodes[i].id).className = 'tab_content';
    ShowHide(site_child_nodes[i].id,'hidden');
}
```